# Jquery table class selector issue

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding the `jquery` table selector

My html

```
<table>
   stuff...
</table>

<table class='table'>
   stuff...
</table>
```

I want to do something on the table that has no table class.

```
 if($('table').hasClass('table')){
     return;       
 }

 ..do something with table that has no 'table' class
```

However, it seems my codes always return because one of my tables has a '`table`' class.

I can't add second class or id on my first table. Is there any way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$("table:not(.table)")
```

it should select any table without that class.

Answer (score 2):

Put a `.each()` around it like this:

```
$('table').each(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('table')){
       // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this -

```
$('table:not(".table")').doSomeStuff();
```